# Openseadragon - Custom Tiles, there is navigator do not showing the image

Tags: deepzoom, openseadragon

i am using OpenSeaDragon, there is Customtiles to showup the images, i can not see the the image exactly for the navigation... please check the issue for the screenshot : http://screencast.com/t/BeP6nyA6M

The code is here :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
                id: "example-custom-tilesource",
                //debugMode: true,
                navigatorSizeRatio: 0.25,
                wrapHorizontal: true,
                showNavigator: true,

                tileSources: {
                    height: 512 * 256,
                    width: 512 * 256,
                    tileSize: 256,
                    minLevel: 8,
                    getTileUrl: function (level, x, y) {
                        console.log("URL::->" + "http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.modestmaps.bluemarble/" + (level - 8) + "-r" + y + "-c" + x + ".jpg")
                        return "http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.modestmaps.bluemarble/" +
                                (level - 8) + "-r" + y + "-c" + x + ".jpg";
                    }
                }
            });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is discussed in https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/325. It's a bug in OpenSeadragon, but you can fix it by removing the minLevel and adjusting getTileUrl so it works for all levels.